# Securing a rails API with shallow routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a JSON api that will be the data source for another rails site (using devise for auth), and have basic token authentication working. 
The API will also be responsible for serving data to a mobile application.

In the API, I have models like: 
User, Books and Chapters
A user has_many :books, a book has_many :chapters. In my routes file, I have

```
shallow do
  resources :users do
    resources :books do
      resources :chapters
    end
  end
end
```

Which results in routes like:

```
/users/:user_id , /users/:user_id/books
/books/:book_id , /books/:book_id/chapters
/chapters/:chapter_id
```

ie 'shallow routes', rather than /users/:user_id/books/:book_id/chapters/:chapter_id

I'm wondering how I should authenticate these, since the chapter doesn't belong to a user It's not just a case of checking the user_id (as that is an attribute of the book model).

```
# chapters_controller
def show
  @chapter = Chapter.find(params[:id])
end
```

Will I have to then get the @chapter's book and then check its user_id? 
Somehow doesn't feel quite right to me. Am I heading in the wrong direction?

thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

A technique I have found that works is for controllers to establish a model scope that restricts what is visible/updateable/destroyable to the currently authenticated user.

I first set the current user and the request information from my controller on my `User` model using the [request_store](https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store) gem which is just a tiny shim over thread local storage with a bit of clean-up.

This makes the user and request information available from any of my models via the `User` class.  I have `User.current`, `User.request` and `User.location` available wherever I need it.

Your controller just has to set `User.current` and `User.request` once it has authenticated the user.  This is incredibly useful when constructing scopes within your models as they can restrict to what is accessible for the current user.

You can define a scope on your model like `visible` which may do a `where(:owner => User.current.id)` or something similar on a related model to restrict what is visible/updatable/destroyable for the current model.

Your controller then just calls `SomeModel.visible`, `SomeModel.updateable`, `SomeModel.destroyable` and it will get a scope that is restricted to what can be read/written/destroyed.  Any `find`, based on that model scope will only succeed if the model is indeed within the scope rules for the user!

Example User model:

```
# models/user.rb
require 'request_store'

class User

  def self.current
    RequestStore.store[:current_user]
  end

  def self.current=(user)
    RequestStore.store[:current_user] = user
  end

  def self.request
    RequestStore.store[:current_request]
  end

  def self.request=(request)
    # stash the request so things like IP address and GEO-IP based location is available to other models
    RequestStore.store[:current_request] = request
  end

  def self.location
    # resolve the location just once per request
    RequestStore.store[:current_location] ||= self.request.try(:location)
  end
end
```

Comment: It's not immediately clear how this solution allows you to authorize models that are dependent on parent models, and are not scoped to the user. In this case, how would you authorize a user to update a chapter given that only the chapter parent is scoped to the user, and the route is shallow...

Comment: The original question was mostly about authentication of users of the api. I expressly avoid defining models in my answer because they are ORM specific. There was no detail given on how users are AUTHORIZED, how roles are assigned/ defined. No models are provided in the question. Controllers are responsible for performing access control based on whatever business rules are defined. A chapter controller would need to scope chapters to only those  books who the currently authenticated user has access to. Its very orm/model specific, and is just a matter of using an appropriate ORM query scope.

Comment: I appreciate that, but the question is clearly on how to authorize a resource that is not directly scoped to a user. The OP is asking if he has to get the book through the chapter and compare its user id to the current user id. I don't see how you have answered that question. At least in its current form, your answer is not clear to me.

Comment: I'll look at adding my note about scoping access in the controller.

Comment: That would be great. Thanks for taking the time to do that.